# ASP.NET MVC with NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, performance

> I want to know few things about [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) with [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate).

1. Is NHibernate the best [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) used with ASP.NET MVC?
2. If so, will NHibernate slow down the application?
3. What can be done to improve performance of an ASP.NET MVC application with NHibernate?

Comment: What do asp.net mvc and an orm have in common? They are 2 totally different things.

Comment: @Mike C: The type of UI framework you build an application on has no influence on how an ORM is working for the applications.

Comment: @Paco now i realize the fact... My question was a month back when i started mvc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Depends. If you are a total newbie you might want to try [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) because it contains all the ORM designer classes that allows you to create entity class by drag and drop.
2. No, it won't. [NHibernate is used](http://nhforge.org/wikis/successstories/default.aspx) by a lot of sites, and it has [first and second level caching feature](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/.../first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate.aspx) that would speed things up by caching the previous operation, so performance isn't really an issue.
3. You can only improve your app after you identify the bottleneck. **Don't premature optimize.**

Comment: The Entity Framework is not for newbies (then again, no ORM is).

Answer (score 6):

I use NHibernate with ASP.NET MVC for [GarageCommerce.com](http://www.garagecommerce.com) and it is very fast even on pretty low budget hardware. The overhead of NHibernate is negligible compared to the raw cost of talking to a database.

There is a [strong community](http://tekpub.com/), proven patterns to follow and support tools like [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/). It's likely that you would end up with a more efficient application than if you had rolled your own database access.

You have a better chance of solving scalability issues with a powerful tool like NH. You can turn on it's 2nd level cache and back it with memcache. There is also work on [NHiberate.Shards](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/10/18/nhibernate-shards-progress-report.aspx) to help you horizontally partition your data.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no best ORM to use with
   ASP.NET MVC. The best ORM is the one
   which meets your needs.
2. No, there is nothing inherent in
   NHibernate that will slow down your
   application.
3. Don't worry so much about
   performance unless it becomes a
   problem in the future. Is there a
   good reason why you have such high
   performance requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Michael, nHibernate is great for CRUD operations and handling of complex operations on business objects. Though it can handle rather complex queries, when it comes to reporting, I'd stick to Crystal reports... and if you have lots of stored procedures, no ORM likes them too much.

Answer (score 0):

just curious...we use crystal reports for our web-based reporting environment...heavy, complex stored procedures that tie up the db for a long time then exporting to pdf.

does converting to an html based solution using an ORM like NHibernate make sense there? seems like there's more flexibility in terms of performance tweaks?